# how to get automation test coverage in jacoco?

Tags: java, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am having my web application running on tomcat , and in separate project i have my test cases which calls  all apis of my app , now i want to check code coverage , covered during api calls from automated test suit.

**Steps I followed:**

1. jacoco dependency in pom.xml of my web app.
2. downloaded jacocoagent.jar
3. set JAVA_OPTS in catalina.sh export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -
   javaagent:/tmp/jars/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/tmp/jars/jacoco.exec,output=file"
4. after all apis killing tomcat
5. copying jacoco.exec file
6. creating html report

but still getting zero coverage , have i missed any thing please suggest

Comment: Did you try the jacoco maven plugin?

Comment: yes to create html from exec file

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ,

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/tmp/jars/jacocoagent.jar=includes=*,destfile=/tmp/jars/jacoco.exec,append=true
```

Comment: In 4th step, you stop all the API services right..?? That you started with this jacoco agent..?